# Blank space when using overflow: auto or scroll on table

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to insert a scroll up and down to a table when it overflows, but for some reason it makes a white space on the right of the columns like the following picture shows: 
http://imageshack.com/a/img922/671/jUnKyG.png

I'm creating the table using the following code:

```
<table ng-if="vm.model.id" width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable no-footer" style="width: 100%; height: 350px; overflow-y: auto; display: block">
```

I also tried overflow-y: scroll but i'm getting the same thing.

So, any ideas on how to fill this blank space with the columns?

Thank you!

Comment: Your table is set to width:100%, so its going to stretch across the full screen. The blank space is just the extra space that is in the webpage because the table doesn't stretch the full width of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I could solve this out with a friend.

For those who are having the same problem, I just added a div above the table with the style that was on the table, like the following:

```
<div style="height: 350px; overflow-y: auto; display: block">

                 <table ng-if="vm.model.id" width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable no-footer" style="margin-top: 0 !important;">
...
```

Thank you!